# network access protection with remedation servers on diffrent vlan

Tags: windows-server-2008, wsus

Dears,,

I am going to implement NAP on Windows Server 2008 r2, but I have question before starting implementation..

I want to implement it on Cisco switch, but  regarding Remediation servers.. I have both WSUS and antivirus on different vlans>>

How can forward users need to update their OS to WSUS, while forward users how need to update their antivirus to another server on diffrent vlan from WSUS ??

How can I implement it ?

Comment: If hosts connected to ports in a particular VLAN need to communicate with hosts connected to ports in another VLAN then you'll need a router to route traffic between the VLAN's.

Comment: there  is a firewall